# C# Binary formatter properties have same value

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, hash

I have hit a small snag when I user the binaryformatter to serialize objects. The whole point for the serialization is so that the values can be passed into a hash function which requires a byte array.

The process I have is, I read the file, using newtonsoft Jsonconvert the json file into a POCO object, do some checks, update values as required and save back to same file in the Json format.

The checks include verifying that the hash value matches from the file to what is regenerated at the beginning of the process. The steps I take are, read file, convert to POCO, serialize using binary formatter, generate hash value, compare both values, if correct, update data and save both the new hash value and object as Json into the file.

However, I have hit a snag when i serialize the object using the binary formatter. If the object has properties where the values are same, the byte output from the serializer is different from when the data is read in from the file to when it is written out. As the values of the byte arrays are different, so are the hash values. Moreover, if the values for the properties are different, then the same hash values are generated and therefore no issues.

My question is why does having the same value causes the byte value to be different when the object is read and written to file.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserAuthorisationData
{
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string forename { get; set; }
    public string initials { get; set; }  

    public UserAuthorisationData()
    {
        surname = "";
        forename = "";
        initials = "";

    }
}
```

E.g

```
var objectA = new UserAuthorisationData()
objectA.surname = "Fred";
objectA.forename = "John";
objectA.initials = "FJ"; 

var objectB = new UserAuthorisationData()
objectB.surname = "John";
objectB.forename = "John";
objectB.initials = "JJ";
```

In the example above, the value of the byte array for objectA is the same, when the hash values are generated both during when data is written out and when the file is read back in.

However, for objectB, the values differ.

Method below to convert object to byte:

```
    protected virtual byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object objectToSerialize)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {

            lock (locker)
            {                   
                formatter.Serialize(fs, objectToSerialize);
                Logger.Debug($"Successfully converted object to bytes for serialization.");
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\ali.kamal\User1.txt", fs.ToArray());

            return fs.ToArray();
        }
   }
```

Call the method on the object

```
ObjectToByteArray(objectA);
ObjectToByteArray(objectB);
```

## Update 1

Thanks Hadi. The hash code is generated using Microsoft's HMACSHA256.computeHash method.

```
protected override string ComputeHash(byte[] objectAsBytes, byte[] key)
    {
        byte[] hashValue = null;
        try
        {
            using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
            {
                hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(objectAsBytes);

            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            EventLogger.LogEvent($"Could not generate SHA256 hash value, exception:{ex.Message}", EventEntryType.Error);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue); 
    }
```

e.g.

```
 string hashvalue = ComputeHash(ObjectToByteArray(objectA), ObjectToByteArray("abcd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to compare the bytes in different way rather than the Hash code method: `Array1.SequenceEqual(Array2)`, Its not clear how you are comparing the Hash Code of both arrays in your question, but I will assume that you are using GetHashCode method, using `Array1.GetHashCode() == Array2.GetHashCode()` is not suitable for your case unless you override the HasCode function. Below is the sample using a Console application for using the `SequenceEqual` method:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new UserData();
            var b = new UserData();

            var aS = ObjectToByte(a);
            var bS = ObjectToByte(b);
            Console.WriteLine("A : {0}", a);
            Console.WriteLine("B : {0}", b);
            // result for empty objects are equal
            Console.WriteLine("A == B ? => {0} \n\n", aS.SequenceEqual(bS));

            a = new UserData()
            {
                ForeName = "A",
                Initials = "CC",
                SurName = "B",
            };

            b = new UserData()
            {
                ForeName = "AX",
                Initials = "CC",
                SurName = "B",
            };

            aS = ObjectToByte(a);
            bS = ObjectToByte(b);

            Console.WriteLine("A : {0}", a);
            Console.WriteLine("B : {0}", b);
            // result for same data type with same object values are equal
            Console.WriteLine("A == B ? => {0} \n\n", aS.SequenceEqual(bS));

            a = new UserData()
            {
                ForeName = "AX",
                Initials = "CC",
                SurName = "B",
            };
            b = a;

            aS = ObjectToByte(a);
            bS = ObjectToByte(b);

            Console.WriteLine("A : {0}", a);
            Console.WriteLine("B : {0}", b);
            // result for different objects are not equal
            Console.WriteLine("A == B ? => {0} \n\n", aS.SequenceEqual(bS));
        }

        static byte[] ObjectToByte(object item)
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(memory, item);
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class UserData
    {
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public string ForeName { get; set; }
        public string Initials { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{{SurName: {0} , ForeName:{1}, Initials:{2}}}", SurName ?? "Empty", ForeName ?? "Empty", Initials ?? "Empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Here a working [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/64D7d9)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Hadi. The hash code is generated using Microsoft's HMACSHA256.computeHash.

Comment: It gave me same result as long as you are using the same `HMACSHA256 ` object, `var h = new HMACSH256(); var aS = h.ComputeHash(ObjectToByte(a)); var bS = h.ComputeHash(ObjectToByte(b));` now `bS.SequenceEqual(aS)` will work fine but if you ComputeHash the object with different HMACSH256 , it will not work.

Comment: Great. But do you know why the values of the byte array differ.

Comment: When you use HMACSHA256() constructor without passing the key, it uses random key, and that is why in my previous comment I said that result will differ. But from your update 1, Its clear that you are passing the key, which should gives you same result if you used the same key!, I tried to reproduce your problem and there was no problem at all, check this sample i made [Sample that works fine for same input your provided](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k9JZkF)